# what is the benefit to the voip apps using PushKit?

Tags: pushkit

what's the benefit if I change my app's notification from APNs to Pushkit?
I try to understand the PushKit from developer.apple.com,but from the documentation I just know the PushKit will instead of my app to invoke my app from background.But is there any different ? just improve battery life

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/EnergyGuide-iOS/OptimizeVoIP.html), you will gain lots of benefits using PushKit, for battery usage for example. However, it should be used only for the VoIP purposes, Otherwise, your application may be rejected for AppStore submission.

> - The device is woken only when VoIP pushes occur, **saving energy**.
> - Unlike standard push notifications, which the user must respond to before your app can perform an action, VoIP pushes go straight to your app for processing.
> - VoIP pushes are considered high-priority notifications and **are delivered without delay**.
> - VoIP pushes can include more data than what is provided with standard push notifications.
> - Your app is automatically relaunched if it’s not running when a VoIP
>     push is received.
> - Your app is given runtime to process a push, even if your app is operating in the background.